# What is "switch car"?

Tags: dialogue, point-break-1991

In the movie *Point Break* I came across the notion of **switch car**.

Here's some context from the movie:

> "Reagan usually does the driving. Stolen **switch car**, they leave it
> runnin’ on the kerb. It looks parked from a distance. When they run,
> they dump the vehicle and they vanish."

What is **switch car**?

Comment: It's a car they switch to from a getaway car.

Comment: So, when he said _When they run, they dump the vehicle..._ which car did he mean? Isn't the getaway car the one they should switch to when running away?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 'getaway car' is the one they use to get away from the bank. Witnesses will be able to identify this car.
A 'switch car' is a car they drive the 'getaway car' to after escaping the bank and switch into so they can then drive to their hideout without anyone connecting them to the bank robbery.

A getaway car is dumped and found by the police. The switch car is hopefully never connected to the bank robbery by the police.